# run a query if another query fetches null value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch max no from invgatepass on the basis of time and date and if it returns null then I want to run another query on the basis of different conditions if that also fails to fetch any data then I want to fetch '1'.
This is something which I want.
But inside `COALESCE` function, second parameter is not allowed to be query.
Can some one solve this problem.
I don't want to use two separate queries after checking the condition inside php code.

```
SELECT COALESCE(
            MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(InwardNo, '-', -1))+1,
            SELECT COALESCE
                    (
                        MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(InwardNo, '-', -1))+1,
                        1
                    ) 
                    FROM 
                    invgatepass 
                    WHERE 
                    DATE(CreationDateTime)=CURDATE() 
                        AND  
                    (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CreationDateTime)) < '17'

            ) 
            AS CODE FROM 
            invgatepass 
            WHERE 
            DATE(CreationDateTime)=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)   
            AND  
            (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CreationDateTime)) >= '17'"
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Please add RDBMS to the question.

Comment: This is not SQL Server. this is mysql.

Answer (score 1):

A subquery is allowed inside the coalesce function, but the subquery must be enclosed within braces.

Look at this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb3d8/2

This query compiles fine because all subqueries are enclosed within braces:

```
SELECT coalesce(
         ( SELECT null ),
         ( SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = 10 ),
         ( SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = 4 ),
         ( SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = 2 )
       ) result
;
```

This query throws a syntax error, because a second subquery has no braces around it:

```
SELECT coalesce(
         ( SELECT null ),
         SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = 10,
         ( SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = 4 ),
         ( SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = 2 )
       ) result
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note: 
You do not need 2 Coalesce:

```
coalesce ( null, null, 1)
```

is about the same as

```
coalesce ( null, coalesce ( null, 1))
```